# Exporting Data from GridDB to any other Database

Tags: griddb

I have been working on a personal project where I collect different types of data from sensors like timestamps, integer values, etc., and storing it in the GridDB cluster because it supports high-throughput data ingestion and real-time querying capabilities. Due to some specific software requirements of my project, I want to export all my data to MongoDB. For example, the database stored in GridDB looks like this:

[image]

And the database stored in MongoDB, which is my requirement for the project, looks like this:

[image]

So to store my data in MongoDB as shown above, first, I configured the cluster as mentioned below:

```
# gs_import/gs_export Properties

clusterName=myCluster
mode=MULTICAST
hostAddress=239.0.0.1
hostPort=31999
jdbcAddress=239.0.0.1
jdbcPort=41999
```

And then tried to code for trying to export the GridDB data to MongoDB, which is as follows:

```js
gs_export -u admin/[password] -d [nameofthecontainer] -c c001
```

I followed this code but could not export all of my data in MongoDB. Only half of the rows or records of the data are being exported and are not complete. Is there any limit to the number of records that can be exported? If so, how can I increase the export limit of the data?